# Dynamic value set in table layout

Tags: php, str-replace

I have an html in variable. In this variable I have a SN_NO,CUST_REF_NO,NAME in td. I need to replace this variable with dynamic values from array. The array value like this

```
$result = array(
            array(
                'sn_no' => '1',
                'cust_ref_no' => 'A123',
                'name' => "AAA",
                'id'=>'111'  
            ),
            array(
                'sn_no' => '2',
                'cust_ref_no' => 'B123',
                'name' => "BBB",
                'id'=>'222' 
            ),
            array(
                'sn_no' => '3',
                'cust_ref_no' => 'C123',
                'name' => "CCC",
                'id'=>'333' 
            ),
);

$tr_html ='<tr>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" width="3%">SN_NO</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="10%">CUST_REF_NO</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="15%">NAME</td>
</tr> ';
```

I need a final result should be like this

```
$tr_html ='<tr>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" width="3%">1</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="10%">A123</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="15%">AAA</td>
</tr> 

<tr>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" width="3%">2</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="10%">B123</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="15%">BBB</td>
</tr> 

<tr>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" width="3%">3</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="10%">C123</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="15%">CCC</td>
</tr> 

';
```

I tried the below code

```
foreach ($result as $key => $val){
   $test = str_replace('SN_NO', $val['sn_no'], $tr_html);
   $test .= str_replace('CUST_REF_NO', $val['cust_ref_no'], $tr_html);
   $test .= str_replace('NAME', $val['name'], $tr_html);

}
echo $test;
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried like this code 
foreach ($result as $key => $val){
   $test = str_replace('SN_NO', $val['sn_no'], $tr_html);
   $test .= str_replace('CUST_REF_NO', $val['cust_ref_no'], $tr_html);
   $test .= str_replace('NAME', $val['name'], $tr_html);
   
}

Comment: Yes, I have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$result = array(
    array(
        'sn_no' => '1',
        'cust_ref_no' => 'A123',
        'name' => "AAA",
        'id'=>'111'
    ),
    array(
        'sn_no' => '2',
        'cust_ref_no' => 'B123',
        'name' => "BBB",
        'id'=>'222'
    ),
    array(
        'sn_no' => '3',
        'cust_ref_no' => 'C123',
        'name' => "CCC",
        'id'=>'333'
    ),
);

$tr_html ='<tr>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" width="3%">SN_NO</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="10%">CUST_REF_NO</td>
    <td class="text-left"  id="abc" style="font-size: 0.6rem;" width="15%">NAME</td>
</tr> ';

$finalResult = '';

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $tmp = $tr_html;
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $tmp = str_replace(strtoupper($key), $value, $tmp);
    }
    $finalResult .= $tmp;
}

echo $finalResult;
```

Comment: $tr_html is the layout it is from database I stored it in varaible. I need to replace the values in SN_NO, CUST_REF_NO,NAME

Comment: I have replaced unswer code above so you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays in str_replace() to replace multiple values at once.

```
$test = '';
foreach ($result as $key => $val){
  $test .= str_replace(
    array('SN_NO', 'CUST_REF_NO', 'NAME'),
    array($val['sn_no'], $val['cust_ref_no'], $val['name']),
    $tr_html);
}
echo $test;
```